# I want change text of Select box without disturbing "option" tag values

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show specific text in select box without changing/removing  text/value of option tag. e.g. When user selects "+91 India" I want to show only "+91"

```js
function countryChange() {
  //some code  
  document.getElementById('mySelect').value = 'some value';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <select id="mySelect" onChange="countryChange()">
    <option value="+91">+91 India</option>
    <option value="+45">+45 Denmark</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the way you can do this**

To  be honest I do not think that what you are trying to do is a good idea. I would recommend creating some `div` and changing its content.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect'),
  options = select.options;

select.onchange = function() {
  var option = options[select.selectedIndex];
  option.text = option.value;
  select.blur();
}

select.onfocus = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].text = options[i].getAttribute("data-text");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="+91" data-text="+91 India">+91 India</option>
    <option value="+45" data-text="+45 Denmark">+45 Denmark</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```